# c++: portable solution to cast and compare member-function pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, pointer-to-member

Before I ask what I want to know, here's a little background:
I'm wrapping a `std::function` in my own class `Function`, which stores some additional data along with the `std::function` object. Later on, I have a `std::vector<Function<Signature>>` that stores a whole bunch of `Function`'s of the same signature (e.g. `void(int)`). These `std::function`'s may represent normal free functions, functors, or member functions that have been bound to an object using `std::bind`.

At some later point, I want to traverse the `std::vector`, and check some properties of the `Function` objects. For example, I want to select every `Function` that is bound to a particular member-function (regardless of the object it will be called on). This means I have to find a way to store these member-function pointers, while discarding their exact type. ***In other words, I need to be able to store a pointer of type `void (A::*)()` and another pointer of type `void (B::*)()` in the same field.***

I used to do this using a `union` to 'cast' the member-function-pointer to a `void*`, but then found out that member-function-pointers are implementation-defined and don't have the same size as pointers. Now I'm looking for a portable solution, and this is what I came up with:

```
class MemFunPtr
{
    friend bool operator==(MemFunPtr const &lhs, MemFunPtr const &rhs);

    enum { SIZE = sizeof(void(MemFunPtr::*)()) };
    char buf[SIZE];

public:
    template <typename T, typename R, typename ... Args>
    MemFunPtr(R (T::*ptr)(Args ...))
    {
        union
        {
            R (T::*memfcn_)(Args ...);
            char buf_[SIZE];
        } caster;

        caster.memfcn_ = ptr;
        memcpy(buf, caster.buf_, SIZE);
    }
};

bool operator==(MemFunPtr const &lhs, MemFunPtr const &rhs)
{
    return memcmp(lhs.buf, rhs.buf, MemFunPtr::SIZE) == 0;
}
```

Now my question is, if this *is* portable. I would be even more happy with a more straightforward way of doing this. I looked in to `std::mem_fn`, but it seems that the type of these objects is unspecified (the examples on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) use `auto`), so I don't think this is where the solution lies.

Comment: This looks overly complicated. Why don't you simply `memcpy(buf, &ptr, sizeof(ptr));`?

Comment: Because that would take the address of a pointer. When dealing with normal pointers, that would just take the address of the pointer that's local to the function, which makes no sense. I don't know if the situation is different with mem-fun-ptr's though...

Comment: Well, you *do* want to copy the contents of that pointer object to `buf`, not the contents of what it points to. So taking the address of the pointer object is perfectly fine, `memcpy` will copy the contents of the object the second argument points to (which is the member function pointer object in my case).

Comment: What overall problem are you trying to solve? [Your code is using two different kinds of a union, which is UB)

Comment: @dyp Ah right. Brainfart on my side. I guess that will work...

Comment: @MatsPetersson Even more background information? Are you sure? I think I have been quite thorough already... What do you mean "two different kinds of a union"?

Comment: The actual issue, as far as I can see, is your comparison: I don't think it is guaranteed that two pointers to the same (member) function have the same representation. I think it is guaranteed that two pointers to different member functions have different representations, though.

Comment: You could, to make sure, store a `type_info*` alongside the buffer; then, compare the types first. Then, dispatch to a function that converts both buffers back to their original type (single-dispatch!), and compare the pointers.

Comment: @dyp Are you sure? Surely, when I pass `&SomeClass::someFun` as a member-function-pointer, it has the same representation on all occasions... won't it?

Comment: But WHY do you want to compare functions like that? What's the bigger problem you are trying to solve? I've written a huge amount of code, and never had the need to compare pointers like that (nor heard of such a need). Possibly, one could consider needing to analyse source code for correctness and check that function calls are going to "the right function", but that sounds much more like something you'd do with a source-code parser (e.g. some variant of libclang/clangtool/etc)

Comment: You're asking about portability, and I don't know of any such guarantee. Of course, if you restrict the portability request to certain (reasonable) systems, you can introduce some nonportability like comparing the buffers directly. By the way, [here's an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5a4d1e01631054e) of what I meant earlier (the type check might be too restrictive though because of inheritance). But I agree with Mats Petersson that a situation where you *need* to compare member function pointers to different type might have an xy-problem.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I'm implementing a signal-slot system, where one can disconnect everything that has been connected to a particular member-function. Therefore, I have to loop over all the `std::function`'s and see which ones correspond to the one I'm looking for. However, when storing `std::function` objects, this information gets lost (I can't use the `target()` member). Therefore, I have to store additional data that describes how the `std::function` object has been constructed. The only way I can think of, is to store the pointer directly, for later comparison.

Comment: Sounds like you should have another identifier to identify the function - there's no absolute guarantee that the compiler doesn't merge two functions that "do the same thing", even if they are written as different member functions originally [albeit I'm not sure I've ever seen that], which would DEFINITELY ruin your plans.

Comment: @MatsPetersson IIRC, VS does indeed do that (with some compiler option), and violates the Standard because of this: the pointers two to different functions compare equal IFF they point to the same function. To consolidate two equal functions, a compiler could use nop slides to give them different addresses. (Pointers to members are slightly different, but I think this point still holds.)

Comment: @JorenHeit D'oh, I should have looked up the comparison rules for pointers-to-members first. The result of some of those comparisons is unspecified anyway, so we cannot do this is an entirely portable way, if the argument to the constructor can be a casted pointer to member function. See [expr.eq]/3

Comment: @MatsPetersson Hmm that would complicate things a lot for the users of my library... There is already an option to add an identifier and I'd like to keep that optional. I'll just make sure that this works with the major compilers and add a note that it might fail on exotic implementations. Thanks!

Comment: @dyp Thanks! I found the reference. It's about `operator==`, which I don't think is relevant when memcpy'ing the pointer object and then comparing byte by byte. It did clear up a lot however so thanks for the help :-)

Comment: What I wanted to say with that comment aboput [expr.eq]/3 is that we need a clear idea of how equality shall be defined between two pointers to member functions. And the Standard itself doesn't even fully specify the equality of two pointers to member functions via `==`. Since the cases where the Standard omits a spec cannot be found at run-time, I think it's impossible to portably extend that definition of equality to all pointers to member functions. Of course, you can simply compare the representations (via char buffers), but I think that does not portably ensure behavioural inequality.

Comment: @dyp I see what you mean. The only thing I can do then is to just compare the buffers and test if this works on GCC, Clang and MSVC. If it does, I'm happy (assuming they won't change their implementation. I'll mention this problem in the docs. Thanks again!

Comment: A lot of interesting points in the discussion, you should have put them into an answer which I could upvote.